# 2 Linked list merge difficulties

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to merge two linked lists.  One issue I have is how I can have my while loop continue to run even after 1 list reaches the end.

E.G:  List1 values: 1, 3;
List 2 values:  2,6,7,8;

Ideally the output would be:  1,2,3,6,7,8
Currently my output is more like 1,2,3 (list1 has reached the end so the loop stops and the other list 2 values don't get added to the list).

Also, I would like for my merge to not be destructive to the original 2 lists that I merge, how can I accomplish this?

```
struct Node
{
    int value;
    Node *next;
};

void addNode(Node* &head, int x) 
{

    Node* temp = new Node;
    temp->value = x;
    temp->next = nullptr;

    if(!head) 
    { 
        head = temp;
        return;
    } 
    else 
    {
        Node* last = head;
        while(last->next) 
        last=last->next;
        last->next = temp;
    }
}


 void merge(Node * &head1, Node * &head2, Node * &head3)
 {
     while (head1 != nullptr && head2 != nullptr)
     {

        if (head1->value < head2->value)
        {
            addNode(head3, head1->value); 
            head1 = head1->next;
        }
        else
        {
            addNode(head3, head2->value);
            head2 = head2->next;
        }

     }
 }
```

Main function:

```
int main()
{
    Node *head = nullptr;
    Node *head2 = nullptr;
    Node *head3 = nullptr;

    for (int i=0; i<=8; i+=2)
        addNode(head, i);

    for (int i=1; i<=5; i++)
        addNode(head2, i);

    merge(head, head2, head3);

    printList(head);
    printList(head2);
    printList(head3);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I showed you already how to merge lists. Can you simply copy and paste?      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30523179/merging-2-linked-lists-and-appending-to-the-end-of-linked-lists-c/30523396#30523396

Comment: Yes I know you showed me, and thank you.  I was using what you wrote as a reference and trying to make my own / similar version so that I better understand how it works that's all.

Answer (score 0):

you forget to merge any remaining items, use this:

```
 // dont pass head1, head2 by reference in method call
 void merge(Node * head1, Node * head2, Node * &head3)
 {
     // and/or use other variables to avoid changing head1, head2
     Node * list1 = head1;
     Node * list2 =  head2;

     while (list1 != nullptr && list2 != nullptr)
     {

        if (list1->value < list2->value)
        {
            addNode(head3, list1->value); 
            list1 = list1->next;
        }
        else
        {
            addNode(head3, list2->value);
            list2 = list2->next;
        }

     }
     // merge any remaining list1 items
     while (list1 != nullptr)
    {
       addNode(head3, list1->value); 
       list1 = list1->next;
    }
     // merge any remaining list2 items
     while (list2 != nullptr)
    {
       addNode(head3, list2->value); 
       list2 = list2->next;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nikos M. answered your first question, his answer is fine, so I won't repeat it. This answer addresses your second question:

> Also, I would like for my merge to not be destructive to the original 2 lists that I merge, how can I accomplish this?

The answer is simple: Don't pass `head1` and `head2` by reference:

```
void merge(Node * head1, Node * head2, Node * &head3)
```

In fact, I would recommend making `head1` and `head2` `const` pointers:

```
void merge(const Node * head1, const Node * head2, Node * &head3)
```

Comment: yes making these head variables const pointers would be better

Answer (score 0):

The while loop exits as soon as either head1 or head2 becomes null. I think you want to add an extra piece of code to just append all remaining elements from the non-empty list (Im assuming they're already sorted).

```
 Node* lastElements = list1 != nullptr ? list1 : list2;
 while( lastElements != nullptr )
 {
     addNode(list3, lastElements->value);
     lastElements = lastElements->next;
 }
```

Add a constructor to Node so that next is always initialised to nullptr. I originally read code wrong an thought you'd missed this initialisation but adding a constructor will simplify your code and mean you wont forget to initialise next pointer if you create nodes elsewhere.

```
Node( int initValue)
: value(initValue)
,  next(nullptr)
{}
```

and the start of your addNode function becomes 1 line instead of 3.

```
Node* temp =  new Node(x);
```

Dont pass in reference to head1 and head2 pointers if the merge is not to be destructive. So something like this.

```
void merge( const Node* head1, const Node* head2, Node3*& outHead3)
{
     //copy pointers in order to iterate through list
     Node* current1 = head1;
     Node* current2 = head2;

     while( current1 != nullptr && current2 != nullptr)
     {
         //as before with relevant name changes
         .
         .
         .
     }

     Node* lastElements = current1 != nullptr ? current1 : current2;
     while( lastElements != nullptr )
     {
         addNode(outHead3, lastElements->value);
         lastElements = lastElements->next;
     }
}
```